# Pyttsx3 runtime error in VScode running Mac OS Sonoma

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, pyttsx3, macos-sonoma

**I wrote an automation code in VScode for Mac OS.**

```
import webbrowser
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

# Function to listen to the my voice input
def listen(language="en-IN"):
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        # Recognize speech based on the selected language
        if language == "en-IN":
            query = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="en-IN")
        else:
            query = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="hi-IN")
        
        print(f"You said: {query}")
        return query.lower()
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Can you repeat?")
        return ""
    except sr.RequestError:
        print("Sorry, there was an error processing the request.")
        return ""

# Function to convert text to speech
def speak(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize the assistant and prompt for the first command
    speak("Hello! I'm friday.How can I help you?")
    language = "en-IN"  # Start with English

    # Continuously listen for commands and respond accordingly
    while True:
        command = listen(language)

        if "switch language" in command:
            # Toggle between English and Hindi
            if language == "en-IN":
                language = "hi-IN"
                speak("Switching to Hindi.")
            else:
                language = "en-IN"
                speak("Switching to English.")

        elif "open youtube" in command:
            # Open YouTube in a web browser
            speak("Opening YouTube...")
            webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com")
            
        elif "bye" in command:
            # Say goodbye and exit the loop
            speak("Goodbye!")
            break
        
        else:
            # Request for a command repetition if not understood
            speak("I didn't understand that command. Can you please repeat?")
```

**
But when I run the program this error pops up:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/friday_trial /friday_code.py", line 38, in <module>
    speak("Hello! I'm your voice assistant. How can I help you?")
  File "/Users/Desktop/friday_trial /friday_code.py", line 32, in speak
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 12, in <module>
    class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 13, in NSSpeechDriver
    @objc.python_method
     ^^^^
NameError: name 'objc' is not defined. Did you mean: 'object'?
```

**How can I fix this?is this just an OS issue or is there an error in my code as I am very new to this field?

Other details:
laptop: m1 Mac book
os: Mac OS Sonoma (14.0)
vscode ver:1.84.2
python ver: 3.12
pyttsx3 ver:2.90
pyobjc versio:10.0**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like [an issue being discussed in github](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/297).

You can try to install package `py3-tts 3.5` according to their discussing by command `pip install py3-tts`

Comment: I tried it but the same error kept popping up. Might just do a fresh install and try it again. Or will have to switch OS it seems. Thanks though.